# Rest Spring Service with IntelliJ doesn't run. What am I'm doing wrong?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, intellij-idea

I have a basic rest app in spring boot, with this configuration

[image]

But when I run it, it show me "build succesful" but stop, instead of being on, receiving request.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the gradle boot-run command, use the application and start that when you do run your application. You get the option in a dropdown.

Comment: that is what I'm doing